# Code works outside of lambda expression, but not from within

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, return

I have the follow code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    fab_action.setOnClickListener(actionSetMyLocationEnable) //passing my lambda
}

private val actionSetMyLocationEnable: (View) -> Unit = { it as FloatingActionButton
    it.isSelected = !it.isSelected
    setMyLocationEnable(it.isSelected) //this call work fine
}

private fun setMyLocationEnable(enable: Boolean) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        return //and this return work nice too
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = enable
}
```

But, when I apply it as follows:

```
private val actionSetMyLocationEnable: (View) -> Unit = { it as FloatingActionButton
    it.isSelected = !it.isSelected
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        return //error 1
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = it.isSelected //error 2
}
```

I'm facing these two errors:

**error 1.**

> 'return' is not allowed here

**error 2.**

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

I know what each error means, but

**My question is:** why does my code work outside of the lambda expression and does not work when inside? And how do I solve this?

**UPDATED**

The [@Rene Ferrari's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312712/6733404) solve the **error 1**. Thanks a lot [@Rene Ferrari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8011713/rene-ferrari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of mTak answer my solution is the following:

```
private val actionSetMyLocationEnable: (View) -> Unit = returnHere@{ it as FloatingActionButton
    it.isSelected = !it.isSelected
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        return@returnHere //error 1
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = it.isSelected //error 2
}
```

You can basically define a label to which you want to return. This label can be named anything except keywords ofcourse. In this example I named it `returnHere`

Comment: World class, thanks! It is working to `error 1.`, but `error 2.` persists. Great advance

Comment: sadly I am not able to reproduce it :(